# Can I watch the full 'Nice Boat' replacement episode anywhere?

Tags: meme, school-days

From [KnowYourMeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/nice-boat): (spoilers for School Days)

> On the day before the airing of the final episode of School Days in Japan, a 16 year old girl killed her father with an axe in Kyoto. Due to an extremely similar scene present in the episode and to avoid relation to the axe murder, TV Kanagawa replaced it with a half hour of unrelated scenery with “Air on a G String” playing in the background. Among the shock and rage expressed among fans, a 4chan user commented “Nice Boat”, referring to the Norwegian ferry shown in the replacement footage. Immediately the phrase became a meme, however is far more popular in Japan than in English speaking countries.

[image]

The part with the boat is easily viewable on Youtube and other sites, but I haven't been able to find the full episode.

Is the episode bundled together with any merchandise or available legally online to stream/download?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full 28-minute version of Nice Boat is apparently [available on Nicovideo](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm1091683) (you'll need to make an account or use a redirector like [nicoviewer](http://nicoviewer.net/sm1091683)). I didn't see the original Nice Boat back when it aired, so I can't say whether it's the real deal, but it certainly looks right to me. The Nice Boat itself makes its first appearance at 04:36.

I would be surprised if Nice Boat were ever included in a home video release of School Days, though. At minimum, it's not included in [the French DVD boxset](http://www.amazon.co.jp/School-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88-DVD-BOX-%EF%BC%88%E5%85%A812%E8%A9%B1-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%87%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA/dp/B00890EFVI/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1437954057&sr=8-2&keywords=school%20days) or in the [2013 Japanese Blu-ray boxset](http://www.amazon.co.jp/School-Days-Blu-ray-BOX-%E5%B9%B3%E5%B7%9D%E5%A4%A7%E8%BC%94/dp/B00AQBT7FW/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1437954057&sr=8-3&keywords=school%20days).